# Backup location in LVM

Tags: backup, lvm

By default, the metadata backup is stored in the /etc/lvm/backup file and the metadata archives are stored in the /etc/lvm/archives file.
What should I do If I want to change directory for backup?
For e.g. I want that my backup folder location will be in this place: /home/user/lvm_backup. Is there any way to do this?